# Limit interaction term to a specific level of the x-axis in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, boxplot, interaction

I am trying to generate a plot that shows the effect on an interaction between a categorical predictor variable and group on a response variable. The effect of the predictor on the response is significant in one group (innoculated) but not the other. Here is the graph I have generated so far.

[image]

There is no reason for the other group (sham) to be split by my categorical predictor  as it has no significant interaction on the response variable within this group. I am a little unclear on what would be the best way to show one level of a vector with an interaction term while leaving the other level undivided in ggplot. Please find the code I used to generate this plot below. Thank you greatly for any suggestions!

```
df.clin.week.snake %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(interaction(expgroup, mortality.type), c("innoculated.euthanasia", "innoculated.mortality", "sham.euthanasia", "sham.mortality")), y = smi_tuk, fill = interaction(expgroup, mortality.type))) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  xlab("")
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. It would help us help you to have a minimal reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Instead of using your data, which we don't have access to, you can just modify your code and use an inbuilt data set, in this case `iris` could work.

Comment: as for your question, 1) I am not sure if your graphs actually tells us that there is no interaction in the sham group. ( You may fare better showing this information). 2) If you want to hide this, you can simply create three groups and plot those